# Referencing JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dom

I've seen similar posts to this but I just can't get this piece of code right.

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"venue_data": 
           {"venue_id":"25",
           "description":"Space Cafe",
          "venue_type": [
           {"type_description":"Cafe"},
           {"type_description":"Free Wifi"},
           {"type_description":"Hangout"}
                       ]
                  }
                        }
           ');

//next line doesn't work :(                         
alert(obj2.venue_data[0].venue_id);
//either do the next two :(                         
alert(obj2.venue_data[0].venue_type[0]);
                         }
alert(obj2.venue_data[0].venue_type[1]);
```

I've tries different things but now I'm just guessing.

ps...without the array in the data it works fine.

Any help welcome.

Thanks,

Ned

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Do any errors show up in the console? Errors are a very useful tool to diagnose issues with your code.

Answer (score 5):

`venue_data` is an object, not an array. You cannot reference it using the `[0]` selector.

Instead, just use the literal:

```
alert(obj2.venue_data.venue_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because `venue_data` is not an `array` it is just an object.

Access it like `console.log(obj2.venue_data.venue_id);`

Instead if it would have been

```
var obj2 = JSON.parse('{"venue_data": ' + 
                            '[{"venue_id":"25",' +
                            '"description":"Space Cafe",' +
                            '"venue_type": [' +
                                            '{"type_description":"Cafe"},' +
                                            '{"type_description":"Free Wifi"},' +
                                            '{"type_description":"Hangout"}' +
                                          ']' +
                            '}]' +
                        '}');
```

Then you should have used `[0]` after `venue_data`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there are some type-errors in your code, and

```
alert(obj2.venue_data[0].venue_id);
```

will not work because

```
obj2.venue_data
```

is not an array.

Here you go:

```
var obj2 = 
{
    "venue_data":
    {
        "venue_id": "25",
        "description": "Space Cafe",
        "venue_type": [
            { "type_description": "Cafe" },
            { "type_description": "Free Wifi" },
            { "type_description": "Hangout" }
        ]
    }
};

alert(obj2.venue_data.venue_id);                 
alert(obj2.venue_data.venue_type[0]);
alert(obj2.venue_data.venue_type[1]);



var obj2witharray = {
    "venue_data":[
     {
        "venue_id": "25",
        "description": "Space Cafe",
        "venue_type": [
            { "type_description": "Cafe" },
            { "type_description": "Free Wifi" },
            { "type_description": "Hangout" }
        ]
     },{
        "venue_id": "26",
        "description": "Universe Cafe",
        "venue_type": [
            { "type_description": "Cafe" },
            { "type_description": "Free Wifi" },
            { "type_description": "Hangout" }
        ]
     }, {
         "venue_id": "27",
         "description": "Earth Cafe",
         "venue_type": [
             { "type_description": "Cafe" },
             { "type_description": "Free Wifi" },
             { "type_description": "Hangout" }
         ]
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, yes the square brackets around the venue makes sense and has used it now.

Comment: obj2 doesn't need `JSON.parse`, it's not a string in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys alot for both answers.
My script had two issues:
1. The venue data was not properly defined and I should have had [ brackets so show the array of venues.
2. I was not creating the json object out out a single string and should have concatenated the strings.

Once again thanks alot.
Ned